# I have configured DKIM but signature verification is failing

Tags: email, dkim

I have configured the dkim for my mail server but it is failing signature verification when testing with dkimvalidator.com.

When testing I found the following result.
[Result Link is here.](http://crystalsoft.com.np/dkim/DKIM,%20SPF,%20and%20Spam%20Assassin%20Validator%20-%20dkimvalidator.com.html)

Can anybody where I am making mistake?

or should spamassasin score 0.111 be a problem? I am sending email to gmail but its going to spam maybe because of dkim config failure I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spam score is fine, when it's under 5 you're good with SA. However your DKIM, well it depends. I Really can't cut and paste a test from a displayed page in the web-browser. But I have a feeling that the DKIM Validator, that system is using is most likely struggling on the fact that you are signing your FROM field twice. Which is valid, but some validators choke on that. If you want a real test, test it with this [Mail Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/email-authentication.html), it uses 4 different independent DKIM validators. It will give you a better idea if your DKIM is truly invalid.

Also change it from simple/simple to relaxed/relaxed. A lot of DKIM Components struggle with the whitespace folding of simple/simple.